# XMLHttpRequest to MongoDB's simple rest interface

Tags: javascript, mongodb, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to fetch data from Mongodb, using javascript inside html (running on apache localhost), but it is not working, request.status is never 200, it is always 0.  Otherwise, on Chrome is says : XMLHttpRequest cannot load hxxp://localhost:28017/newdb/newcollection/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin  hxxp://localhost is therefore not allowed access.

although mozilla/opera don't give this error, but in any case  request.status is never 200, and request.responseText is always empty.

whereas, when I just  browse this address from the browser, hxxp://localhost:28017/newdb/newcollection/    it displays the  collection,  but not from xmlhttprequest.

here is the javascript code:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
request.open("GET", "http://localhost:28017/newdb/newcollection/", true);   
request.withCredentials="true"; 

request.onreadystatechange = handleReadyStateChange;    
request.send();         

function handleReadyStateChange() {    
       if (request.readyState == 4) {        
            if (request.status == 200) { 
        document.write(request.responseText);       
             }
       }
    }
```

Thanks a lot for any kind of suggestion, there are some similar posts, but none of the suggestions worked :(

Cheers

Comment: is there a reason your not using JQuery or another library to abstract the AJAX Request? It will help you with cross browser conflicts.

Comment: @Matt617, thanks for the reply, but the main problem is not the cross browser conflict, the thing is that request.status is always 0, never 200, and request.responseText is empty.  May be it is due to a Cross Origin Resource Sharing issue but I am not sure how to solve it.

Comment: have you tried to use a jsonP style query? if you use JQuery it would look like this:

$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: "jsonp",
  success: function (data) {
    console.log(data)
    alert(data);
  }
});

and allow you to go cross domain

Comment: @Matt617 thanks for the suggestion. yeah finally it works with JSONP, however there is also another requirement,  to allow JSONP, MongoDB has to be started with an extra option --jsonp  i.e  ./mongod --rest --jsonp

Comment: FYI, the MongoDB simple REST interface is only intended for use in a **development** environment and does not include any support for authentication even when `auth` is enabled. It provides [administrative access](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/security-interface/#rest-api) so use with caution. If you want to build a public-facing service using XMLHttpRequest you should look into [alternative REST interfaces](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/) and properly securing requests with tokens or authentication.